# Grouping the combination results into a list with sub-lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have list `a`:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Then I create all three-element combinations of this list. The results are grouped in sublistach because of matching to the equivalent in the form of a binary 3-bit string. For example, the result `[0,4,5]` corresponds to the sequence `001`, because each even number corresponds to 0, and the odd number 1.

The code I use with the comments:

```
import itertools as it
import itertools

# I create three-element combinations of zeros and ones
combinations_3bit = list(map(list, itertools.product([0,1], repeat=3)))
# output: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

# I create a list of strings with values from the list `3bit_combinations`
a=[]
for i in range(len(combinations_3bit)):
    a2 =''.join(map(str, [1 if x%2 else 0 for x in combinations_3bit[i]]))
    a.append(a2)
# output: ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111'] 

# I remove repetitions in pairs of type 001 with 100, 011 with 110, etc.
combinations_3bit_without_repetition = [v for k, v in enumerate(a) if v[::-1] not in a[:k]] 
# output: ['000', '001', '010', '011', '101', '111'] 

b = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

good = []
for i in range(len(combinations_3bit_without_repetition)):
    c=[]
    for u in it.combinations(b, 3):       
        u1 = list(u)                  
        y =''.join(map(str, [1 if x%2 else 0 for x in u1]))
        if y == combinations_3bit_without_repetition[i]:
           c.append(u1)
    good.append(c) 

# output: [[[0, 2, 4]], [[0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 5], [0, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5]], [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4], [0, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]], [[0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 5], [0, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]], [[1, 3, 5]]]
```

Can this be solved nicer and more economically?
Because the above solution seems to be "around" and for example the function `it.combinations` returns after each index`i` from the list `combinations_3bit_without_repetition` all possible combinations, and only then the condition screens only the matching ones. In the case of large lists, this solution is weak;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much better way to generate the binary strings that you need:

```
import itertools

strings = ['{0:03b}'.format(i) for i in range(8)]
b = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
combinations = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(b, 3)]

dct = {}

for x in combinations:
  y = ''.join(str(j%2) for j in x)
  if y in dct:
    dct[y].append(x)
  else:
    dct[y] = [x]

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'010': [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4], [0, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]], '011': [[0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 5], [0, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5]], '001': [[0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 5], [0, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5]], '000': [[0, 2, 4]], '101': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]], '100': [[1, 2, 4]], '110': [[1, 3, 4]], '111': [[1, 3, 5]]}
```

Check to see if this does what you need.  It creates a dictionary, where each key is a length 3 binary string, and each value is an array of combinations that match the binary string.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with the binary strings there is a smaller problem. I care more about optimizing the creation of the `good` list.

Comment: Can you clarify more what you want as your output? You want all length 3 permutations of your list that match a certain pattern?

Comment: just like that. that is, for example, finding all combinations to the 000, i001 pattern, and so on. of course, without some repetitions of type [0,2,5] and [5,2,0]. but this is also one of the smaller problems;)

Comment: So the combination `[0,1,2]` corresponds to `'010'`, and therefore you want `[0,1,2]` in `good`?

Comment: that's exactly what it's all about.

Comment: of course, the results of each representation in another sub-list.

Comment: I will have to do a bit of it for my purposes, but it works great. thanks!

Comment: Nice approach.  You can use a `collections.defaultdict` instead a regular dict.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `itertools.groupby` solution using your `b` and your `combinations_3bit_without_repetition`:

```
def binarize(x):
    return ''.join(map(str, map((1).__and__, x)))

srted = sorted(itertools.combinations(b, 3), key=binarize)
allowed = set(combinations_3bit_without_repetition)
result = [list(grp) for bn, grp in itertools.groupby(srted, binarize) if bn in allowed]

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[[(0, 2, 4)], [(0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 5), (0, 4, 5), (2, 4, 5)], [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 4), (0, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)], [(0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 5), (0, 3, 5), (2, 3, 5)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 5), (1, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)], [(1, 3, 5)]]
```

Comment: I like this solution. Very clean